# CMake finding wrong version of python

Tags: python, cmake, homebrew, pythoninterpreter

How can I fix the error of:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required
  is at least "3" (found /usr/local/bin/python3)
```

where CMake is finding the wrong version of python.

How can I fix this, as

```
python --version
Python 2.7.14

geoheil@eduroam-078-104-029-050 ~                                                                                           [17:34:02]
> $ python3 --version
Python 3.6.5
```

already returns the right versions of python which were installed via home-brew?

## edit

here some clarifications:
- cmake also was installed via home-brew

```
which python
/usr/local/bin/python

geoheil@geoheils-MacBook ~                                                                                                   [8:01:12]
> $ which python2
/usr/local/bin/python2

geoheil@geoheils-MacBook ~                                                                                                   [8:01:15]
> $ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

geoheil@geoheils-MacBook ~                                                                                                   [8:01:18]
> $ echo $PATH
/Users/geoheil/development/flutter/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/usr/local/bin:/Library/oracle/instantclient_12_1
```

### edit 2

some more clarifications

```
> $ which make
/usr/bin/make

geoheil@geoheils-MacBook ~                                                                                                  [11:20:25]
> $ which cmake
/usr/local/bin/cmake

geoheil@geoheils-MacBook ~                                                                                                  [11:20:27]
    > $ ls -l /usr/local/bin/make
    ls: /usr/local/bin/make: No such file or directory
ls /usr/local/bin |grep make
automake
automake-1.16
ccmake
cmake
cmakexbuild
```

a detailed stack tracke

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required
  is at least "3" (found /usr/local/bin/python3)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:376 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPythonInterp.cmake:155 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:696 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

### brew doctor output

```
brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in the App Store.


Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
  /usr/local/lib/libnnz11.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libociei.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libocijdbc11.dylib

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  docker-machine
  ghostscript
  numpy
  gprof2dot
  grass7
  matplotlib
  gnupg
  ruby

Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
  /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain.backup
  /usr/local/bin/hyperkit.backup
  /usr/local/bin/notary.backup
  /usr/local/bin/vpnkit.backup
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/plugins/designer/libqscintillaplugin.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/Qsci.pyi
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/Qsci.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/Qt.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtDeclarative.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtDesigner.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtHelp.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtMultimedia.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtNetwork.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtOpenGL.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtScript.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtScriptTools.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtSql.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtSvg.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtTest.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtWebKit.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtXml.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtXmlPatterns.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/__init__.py
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/pyqtconfig.py
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/sip.pyi
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/sip.so
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/sipconfig.py
  /usr/local/lib/qt-4/python2.7/site-packages/sipdistutils.py

geoheil@geoheils-MacBook ~                                                                                                   [1:52:27]
> $
```

To reproduce execute:

```
brew install -v --no-sandbox qgis/qgisdev/qgis3-dev --with-grass --with-r
```

The exact stacktrace is:

```
==> cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/qgis3-dev/3.0.1 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -Wno-dev -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/opt/qt;/usr/local/opt/qt5-webkit;/usr/local/opt/qscintilla2;/usr/local/opt/qwt;/usr/local/opt/qwtpolar;/usr/local/opt/qca;/usr/local/opt/gdal2;/usr/local/opt/gsl;/usr/local/opt/geos;/usr/local/opt/proj;/usr/local/opt/libspatialite;/usr/local/opt/spatialindex;/usr/local/opt/expat;/usr/local/opt/sqlite;/usr/local/opt/libzip;/usr/local/opt/flex;/usr/local/opt/bison;/usr/local/opt/fcgi -DENABLE_TESTS=FALSE -DENABLE_MODELTEST=FALSE -DQGIS_MACAPP_BUNDLE=0 -DQGIS_MACAPP_INSTALL_DEV=FALSE -DWITH_QWTPOLAR=TRUE -DWITH_INTERNAL_QWTPOLAR=FALSE -DWITH_ASTYLE=FALSE -DWITH_QSCIAPI=TRUE -DWITH_STAGED_PLUGINS=TRUE -DWITH_GRASS=FALSE -DWITH_CUSTOM_WIDGETS=TRUE -DWITH_QTWEBKIT=TRUE -DGDAL_LIBRARY=/usr/local/opt/gdal2/lib/libgdal.dylib -DGEOS_LIBRARY=/usr/local/opt/geos/lib/libgeos_c.dylib -DGSL_CONFIG=/usr/local/opt/gsl/bin/gsl-config -DGSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/opt/gsl/include -DGSL_LIBRARIES='-L/usr/local/opt/gsl/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas' -DWITH_SERVER=TRUE -DPOSTGRES_CONFIG=/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/pg_config -DWITH_GRASS7=TRUE -DGRASS_PREFIX7='/usr/local/opt/grass7/grass-base' -DWITH_GLOBE=FALSE -DWITH_ORACLE=FALSE -DWITH_QSPATIALITE=FALSE -DWITH_APIDOC=FALSE -DWITH_3D=FALSE -DCLANG_TIDY_EXE= ..
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 9.1.0.9020039
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 9.1.0.9020039
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/clang -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/clang++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- QGIS version: 3.1.0 Master (30100)
-- Found GRASS 7: /usr/local/opt/grass7/grass-base (7.2.2, off_t size = )
-- Looking for openpty
-- Looking for openpty - found
-- Looking for proj_info in /usr/local/opt/proj/lib/libproj.dylib
-- Looking for proj_info in /usr/local/opt/proj/lib/libproj.dylib - found
-- Found Proj: /usr/local/opt/proj/lib/libproj.dylib
-- Found GEOS: /usr/local/opt/geos/lib/libgeos_c.dylib (3.6.2)
-- Found GDAL: /usr/local/opt/gdal2/lib/libgdal.dylib (2.2.4)
-- Found Expat: /usr/local/opt/expat/lib/libexpat.dylib
-- Found Spatialindex: /usr/local/opt/spatialindex/lib/libspatialindex.dylib
-- Found Qwt: /usr/local/opt/qwt/lib/qwt.framework (6.1.3)
-- Found libzip: /usr/local/opt/libzip/lib/libzip.dylib
-- Found Sqlite3: /usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
-- Found PostgreSQL: /usr/local/lib/libpq.dylib
-- Found SpatiaLite: /usr/local/opt/libspatialite/lib/libspatialite.dylib
-- Looking for gaiaStatisticsInvalidate in /usr/local/opt/libspatialite/lib/libspatialite.dylib
-- Looking for gaiaStatisticsInvalidate in /usr/local/opt/libspatialite/lib/libspatialite.dylib - found
-- Qt WebKit support enabled
-- Found Qt version: 5.10.1
-- Found QScintilla2: /usr/local/opt/qscintilla2/lib/libqscintilla2_qt5.dylib (2.10.4)
-- Found QtKeychain: /usr/local/lib/libqt5keychain.dylib
-- Found QCA: /usr/local/opt/qca/lib/qca-qt5.framework (2.1.3)
-- QtCore/QCA include/lib variables missing or CMake is cross-compiling,
--   skipping QCA OpenSSL plugin C++ check
-- Found Libtasn1: /usr/local/include
-- Pedantic compiler settings enabled
-- Debug output enabled
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required
  is at least "3" (found /usr/local/bin/python3)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:376 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPythonInterp.cmake:155 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:696 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/qgis3-dev-20180420-31869-62l4n4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

==> Formula
Tap: qgis/qgisdev
Path: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/qgis/homebrew-qgisdev/Formula/qgis3-dev.rb
==> Configuration
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.6.1
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 5a2817cb023ca5e929fe030d423002992bdabf1b
Last commit: 4 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: a2db529ab071d34fe50dbb6b104fa04a85c39fbf
Core tap last commit: 4 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_ENABLE_AUTO_UPDATE_MIGRATION: 1
CPU: octa-core 64-bit kabylake
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.3 => /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.3/bin/ruby
Clang: 9.1 build 902
Git: 2.17.0 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 10, 1.8.0_162, 1.8.0_131
macOS: 10.13.4-x86_64
CLT: N/A
Xcode: 9.3
XQuartz: 2.7.11 => /opt/X11
==> ENV
HOMEBREW_CC: clang
HOMEBREW_CXX: clang++
CXXFLAGS: -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/grass7/7.2.2/grass-base/include
SDKROOT: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk
MAKEFLAGS: -j8
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local/opt/bison:/usr/local/opt/flex:/usr/local/opt/openssl:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/sqlite:/usr/local/opt/qt:/usr/local/opt/qt5-webkit:/usr/local/opt/expat:/usr/local/opt/libxml2:/usr/local/opt/gdal2:/usr/local/opt/gdal2-python:/usr/local/opt/gettext:/usr/local/opt/libffi:/usr/local/opt/openblas:/usr/local
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/apache2:/opt/X11/include:/opt/X11/include/freetype2:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/X11/lib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries
CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH: /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks:/usr/local/opt/qt/Frameworks:/usr/local/opt/qt5-webkit/Frameworks:/usr/local/opt/python@2/Frameworks:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/xz/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/python/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/qt5-webkit/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/python@2/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/qca/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/gsl/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/expat/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/proj/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/spatialindex/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libzip/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libtasn1/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/json-c/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/pcre/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/freexl/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libspatialite/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/gdal2/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/mpfr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/isl/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/fftw/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/fontconfig/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/pixman/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/glib/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/cairo/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/little-cms2/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/r/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR: /usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/10.13:/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/X11/share/pkgconfig
HOMEBREW_SDKROOT: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk
ACLOCAL_PATH: /usr/local/opt/bison/share/aclocal:/usr/local/opt/libxml2/share/aclocal:/usr/local/opt/gettext/share/aclocal:/usr/local/share/aclocal:/opt/X11/share/aclocal
PATH: /usr/local/Cellar/qgis3-dev/3.0.1/libexec/python/bin:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/super:/usr/local/opt/cmake/bin:/usr/local/opt/ninja/bin:/usr/local/opt/bison/bin:/usr/local/opt/flex/bin:/usr/local/opt/gdbm/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin:/usr/local/opt/xz/bin:/usr/local/opt/python/bin:/usr/local/opt/qt/bin:/usr/local/opt/python@2/bin:/usr/local/opt/sip/bin:/usr/local/opt/pyqt/bin:/usr/local/opt/qca/bin:/usr/local/opt/gsl/bin:/usr/local/opt/expat/bin:/usr/local/opt/proj/bin:/usr/local/opt/libpng/bin:/usr/local/opt/freetype/bin:/usr/local/opt/numpy/bin:/usr/local/opt/fcgi/bin:/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin:/usr/local/opt/libzip/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtasn1/bin:/usr/local/opt/jpeg/bin:/usr/local/opt/giflib/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtiff/bin:/usr/local/opt/libgeotiff/bin:/usr/local/opt/geos/bin:/usr/local/opt/pcre/bin:/usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin:/usr/local/opt/gdal2/bin:/usr/local/opt/gdal2-python/bin:/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:/usr/local/opt/lbzip2/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/unixodbc/bin:/usr/local/opt/gcc/bin:/usr/local/opt/fftw/bin:/usr/local/opt/wxmac/bin:/usr/local/opt/fontconfig/bin:/usr/local/opt/glib/bin:/usr/local/opt/cairo/bin:/usr/local/opt/little-cms2/bin:/usr/local/opt/ghostscript/bin:/usr/local/opt/grass7/bin:/usr/local/opt/r/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Error: qgis/qgisdev/qgis3-dev 3.0.1 did not build
```

which cmake
/usr/local/bin/cmake

Comment: To start you should tell us all that you are attempting to use Homebrew to install `cmake`. Then it would be good to get the output of `which python`, `which python2` and `which python3` and perhaps `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Please see the changes.

Comment: What does `which make` return? It probably returns `/usr/local/bin/make` but let's check. I'd also check `ls -l /usr/local/bin/make`. Might also be worth an uninstall and install of make.

Comment: "CMake" and "make" are **different things**, and the error message `CMake Error ...` belongs **only to CMake**. Probably, you want to replace all occurence of word "make" in your post with "CMake" (or with `cmake` if refer to the executable). Start with the title and end with `which cmake`.

Comment: See the updated post

Comment: Did you try: `brew remove cmake` followed by `brew install cmake`?

Comment: And also can you add the output of `brew doctor`?

Comment: See the output of brew doctor above - unfortunately, the error remains the same after reinstalling CMake.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler I think that the other commenters are asking you to provide a [mcve]. Please add a minimal `CMakeLists.txt` that illustrates the behavior that you're seeing, and the full error stack that results.